# Empty rows result from sql query

Tags: mysql

I don't have much experience with php scripts and I am not sure why this code is not working.
I'm pretty sure there is something wrong with it but I am not sure what it is. I always get 0 rows as the result.

```
    <?php

$localhost = mysql_connect("localhost","eiarzate_em","roots") or trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
mysql_select_db("eiarzate_sensordata", $localhost);
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query_search = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."' AND password = '".$password."'";
$query_execute = mysql_query($query_search) or die(mysql_error());

//if-else

$rows = mysql_num_rows($query_execute);


if(rows == 0){
echo "No user was found";
}else{
echo "User found";
}

?>
```

Im pretty sure it's my query statement but I have been tinkering with it for a few ours and I looked for a solution but I had no luck any help is appreciated.

Comment: Impossible to tell without looking at your inputs and your data. I can see a TON of security issues with this code, however that you MUST address before this code is ever ran on an internet facing system. For starters, take a look at this comic: http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: 1. Stop using `mysql_*`. They've been deprecated for years and are no longer supported. Use `PDO` or `mysqli_`. 2. Your code is very much open to SQL injection. A username of `administrator' --` would log me in as the user "administrator" without knowing the password. Use prepared statements and bind variables to avoid this. 3. **DO NOT** use plaintext passwords. Use a hashing algorithm such as `password_hash`.

Comment: Open your mysql-log and check if the command was send. Wouldnt be bad to know.

Comment: WHAT if your form isnt working? If username & password are empty, your query cant catch any rows!? How bad we cant see the form.

Comment: I figured it out thank you community. Thank you for the good points on security. For my purposes though I don't have to worry so much about security but I will focus more on that if I ever have sensitive info on the database or server.